# Append jQuery toJavaScript's native

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to use native JavaScript for jQuery's `.append()` function

```js
$('.edge select').append('<option val="1">One</option>');
// How to do the above in plain JS ?
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="gridMT_pageBar_bottom_changeItemPerPage" class="edge">
  <select onchange="SweetDevRia.$(&#39;gridMT&#39;).changeItemPerPage(this.value);">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100" selected="selected">100</option>
  </select>
  /page
</div>
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. This one line question can be interpreted numerous ways .. most make you look bad for not doing a little research on your own to attempt a solution. The others make question very unclear what is being asked. update question with proper details and if you have made attaempts add that code

Comment: @charlietfl actually there was more than one line it was just not well formatted.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yeah that helps a tiny bit....still a pretty shaky question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector(".edge select").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<option val="1">One</option>');
```

```html
<div class="edge">
  <select></select>
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

You asked for `.append()` where probably you needed `.prepend()` (since you're trying to **prepend** a **lower** value) therefore instead of `"beforeend"` you should use respectively `"afterbegin"`

```js
var SELECT = document.querySelector(".edge select");
SELECT.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<option val="1">1</option>');
```

```html
<div id="gridMT_pageBar_bottom_changeItemPerPage" class="edge">
  <select onchange="SweetDevRia.$(&#39;gridMT&#39;).changeItemPerPage(this.value);">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100" selected="selected">100</option>
  </select>
  /page
</div>
```